# aes256 results differ in C# (Windows) and C++ (Ubuntu) implementation

Tags: c#, .net, c++, aes, crypto++

Here are the codes for aes256 with cbc and pkcs7 padding (and a password) encryption on C (Windows and C++ (Ubuntu using libcrypto++). The encryption result is not the same. Why?

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;


public static class AESEncryption
{
    public static string Encrypt(byte[] PlainTextBytes, byte[] KeyBytes, string InitialVector)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] InitialVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InitialVector);
                RijndaelManaged SymmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
                SymmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
               // SymmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                ICryptoTransform Encryptor = SymmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KeyBytes, InitialVectorBytes);
                MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream CryptoStream = new CryptoStream(MemStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                CryptoStream.Write(PlainTextBytes, 0, PlainTextBytes.Length);
                CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                byte[] CipherTextBytes = MemStream.ToArray();
                MemStream.Close();
                CryptoStream.Close();
                //return ByteToHexConversion(CipherTextBytes);

                return Convert.ToBase64String(CipherTextBytes);
            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
                throw a;
            }
        }
    }
namespace aes
{ class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string FinalValue = AESEncryption.Encrypt( Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("My Text"),  Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("My Password"), "0000000000000000");

            Console.WriteLine(FinalValue);

        }
}

}
```

C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <sstream>
#include "base64.h"

int main()
{


std::string result;
std::stringstream out;

    // ctx holds the state of the encryption algorithm so that it doesn't
    // reset back to its initial state while encrypting more than 1 block.
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);


    std::string keyy="My Password";// in char key[] My Password is written in bytes
    unsigned char key[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x4d,0x79, 0x20, 0x50, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x77,
                   0x6f, 0x72, 0x64};
    unsigned char iv[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
   assert(sizeof(key) == 32);  // AES256 key size
    assert(sizeof(iv) ==  16);   // IV is always the AES block size

    // If data isn't a multiple of 16, the default behavior is to pad with
    // n bytes of value n, where n is the number of padding bytes required
    // to make data a multiple of the block size.  This is PKCS7 padding.
    // The output then will be a multiple of the block size.
    std::string plain("My Text");
    std::vector<unsigned char> encrypted;
    size_t max_output_len  = plain.length() + (plain.length() % 16) + 16;
    encrypted.resize(max_output_len);

    // Enc is 1 to encrypt, 0 to decrypt, or -1 (see documentation).
    EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv, 1);

    // EVP_CipherUpdate can encrypt all your data at once, or you can do
    // small chunks at a time.
    int actual_size = 0;
    EVP_CipherUpdate(&ctx,
             &encrypted[0], &actual_size,
             reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&plain[0]), plain.size());

    // EVP_CipherFinal_ex is what applies the padding.  If your data is
    // a multiple of the block size, you'll get an extra AES block filled
    // with nothing but padding.
    int final_size;
    EVP_CipherFinal_ex(&ctx, &encrypted[actual_size], &final_size);
    actual_size += final_size;

    encrypted.resize(actual_size);

    for( size_t index = 0; index < encrypted.size(); ++index )
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') <<
            static_cast<unsigned int>(encrypted[index]);
         //std:: cout<< "val: "<< static_cast<unsigned int>(encrypted[index]) << std::endl;

        out<< std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned int>(encrypted[index]);
    }
    result = out.str();
    std::cout <<"\n"<< result<< "\n";

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);


    //
    std::cout<<"decript..\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

your IV in c# is a string containing '0' and not '\0' and your IV in c++ does contain '\0' the ascii value of '0' and '\0' are different.

replace the following line

```
string FinalValue = AESEncryption.Encrypt( Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("My Text"),  Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("My Password"), "0000000000000000");
```

with

```
string FinalValue = AESEncryption.Encrypt( Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("My Text"),  Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("My Password"), "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0");
```

that should do the trick I think.

20110111

try replacing `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("My Password")` with `new byte[]{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x4d,0x79, 0x20, 0x50, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x77,0x6f, 0x72, 0x64}`
in your c# code should yell different result

Comment: can you please tell me how to make the correction? Or what to change? Please:). Thx(write the code). The password is a string value:"xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xx". Like this for example.

Comment: THX a lot dvhh. I forget to mention that i need the iv to be set to 0. HOw should I set the both iv in c# and c++ to 0?

Comment: to "0000000000000000" or to an array of 0 ?

Comment: To any array of 0. ON aes 256 encryption i guess the iv's lenght is set to 16.

Comment: I need an aes 256 with cbc and padding and of course a secret key - password on both systems. C++ ubuntu and .net c# windows. The results need to be the same...I don't know how to correct my code:(. I am really stacked...:(.

Comment: write "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" instead of "0000000000000000" in your c# code

Comment: i still have different results:(

Comment: you don't seem to use libcrypto++ which makes guessing more difficult

Comment: ok it's libssl-dev, what is your version ? And if you could put the 2 encrypted string that you obtain

Comment: And your c++ output hexadecimal where your c# output base64 data

Comment: conversion to hexadecimal in c# BitConverter.ToString(CipherTextBytes)

Comment: the lib in ubuntu is openssl 0.9.8. I don't know what other way to write the string password :(.

Comment: THX!! YOU WERE RIGHT!! I DID CHANGE THE KEY AND NOW I RECEIVE THE SAME RESULT ON BOTH SYSTEMS. :)THX A LOT!!!!!!!!! I do want to ask you how can i change the string"password" in bytes in order to work properly? or is there other way to give the key in string and not in bytes ?

Comment: why the result on .net is different if i use encoding.ascii.getbytes for the one with 0x00....?

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the equivalent for the string "my password" in byte[]{0x????} written on 32 bytes?

Comment: use http://home1.paulschou.net/tools/xlate/, "my password" => new byte[]{0x6d, 0x79, 0x20, 0x70, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x64}; but in your case "My Password" => {0x4d, 0x79, 0x20, 0x50 ,0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x64}

Comment: anyway writing "My Password" is an array of char in C and C++ and should work as is or with minor typecast.

Comment: Another thing you could choose my answer as correct for your question also :)

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on dvhh's answer:

You probably should not use a zero IV anyhow.  An IV can be useful to avoid identical plaintexts (or plaintexts with identical prefixes) from being recognizably identical to an attacker.  It's OK for the IV itself to be plaintext; so you could just randomly generate the IV and prepend it to the output to permit decryption.

To get a secure random IV in .NET, so something like:

```
byte[] initialVectorBytes = new byte[16];
using(var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    rng.GetBytes(initialVectorBytes);
//...
using(var memStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    memStream.Write(IV,0,16); //to permit decryption later. 
    //...
}
```

BTW, the usual practice in C# is to use a lowercase letter at the start of a variable or parameter name - you'll make your code more readable to others if you follow suit.

Comment: I do not need an randomly IV. I have to set it to 0. I also need my key to be a specific password:"xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx". I am doing aes on both .net and ubuntu. I have problems with the results ..they are different. Like dhvv said.I would like to set the both values to 0 not \0. How can I do that? Can you write the code? I would really appreciate

Comment: probably because "she" want to compare to an existing baseline for the 2 algorithms, or doesn't understand the crypto meaning of an IV.

Comment: These are the condittions for the webservice. AES 256 with cbc, password(the key is a password) and padding 7, iv set to 0. I have to write it in c++ ubuntu and check the results with a code written in .net c# on windows. It should be the same. I have to send messages on a webservice which is made on .net.

Comment: NEED HELP!! I would really appreciate to send me an c++ code with these conditions!! I also have to make the encryption on c# with the sme condition. ...

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same issue when I was working on encryption between PHP and a .NET web service.

I created a sample project on github to show a working example of Rijndael encryption between PHP and NET.:
https://github.com/dchymko/.NET--PHP-encryption

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use IV as 16 bytes array of value 0x00, then change the C# code

```
byte[] InitialVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InitialVector);
```

to

```
byte[] InitialVectorBytes = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

You can also change the function to ommit the 3rd parameter